# find total sum in react

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

I have the below data

```
day1  product1     100    cash
day1  product2     10     cash
day1  product2     20     card
day2  product1     40     card
day2  product3     30     cash
day2  product1     10     card
day2  product2     60     card
day3  product3     70     cash
day3  product1     20     cash
day3  product2     40     card
```

how to find total sum for each day with cash and total sum with card using react and draw graph based on it

Comment: What is your data structure? Can you show an example object?

Comment: I have this as csv file, need to find total amount paid using cash and using card on that particular day @NickMcCurdy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an array of the parsed CSV items like this:

```
const items = [
  { day: "day1", product: "product2", amount: 100, payment: "cash" }
  // ...
]
```

You can get the totals like this:

```
const sumItems = items.map(item => item.amount).reduce((a, b) => a + b)

const cash = sumItems(items.filter(({ type }) => type === "cash"))
const card = sumitems(items.filter(({ type }) => type === "card"))
```